# Regex match for optional trailing slash

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match:

```
/app
/app/
/app/**
```

but not:

```
/app**
```

The trailing slash should be optional. I can't quite get it to work.

`^/app/([^/]*)/?` matches `/app/` and `/app/**`, but not `/app`.

Comment: `**` means any path like in `/app/**` could be `/app/a/path/to/something` ? Or `**` literally ?

Comment: yes, any path would match (like your example of /app/a/path/to/something). is there some kind of regex that says "either end here or have this character (/) and anything else. I tried ends with in an or but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\/app((\/\w+)+|\/?)$
```

Comment: that's very close! but since it only matches word characters, /app/whatever/another/path won't match. i see where you're going, though. i'll work with that and see what i can come up with. thanks!

Comment: In that case, try something simpler like `#^/app(/.*)?$#`

Comment: wow. that was totally in front of my face the whole time. thanks alot, @cbuckley!

Answer (score 12):

This will work:

```
^/app(/[^/]*)?
```

edit:
    This will also work:

```
^/app(/.*)?
```

Comment: no, it won't, because of the leading slash in the optional part.

Comment: But it won't allow /app/foo/bar.

Comment: maybe not for the subexpression, but it still matches. i do appreciate your answer, though. thank you.

Comment: It will even allow  /app/foo/bar because of the missing end-operator. Though it won't be saved. That said, I would modify the string to:
^/app(/.*)?
(Added to original post)

Comment: No, you are right, it will not match it, but as far as I understood the TE he just needed a leeding "/app"-directory. So it would be sufficient, to check the leading string

Comment: The lack of end operator causes /appfoo to match as well, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

Using this in production right now:

```
^\/app((\/.*$)|$)
```

Here's an example of it on RegExr

https://regexr.com/41bo1

Comment: That's what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
   ^/app(/[^/]+)*/?
```

I'not sure about the ** - thing, but can you really be needing something like this ???

```
   ^/app/?(/[^/]+)*/?$
```

Comment: thank you but that will still match /app**. i want to match exactly /app, /app/, or /app/anything**. i'm struggling to fing the regex that says "here you must have a / or the end".

Comment: What is ** here? Some random chars or two consecutive *'s?

Comment: any random character. sorry for the lack of description.

Comment: Then how is /app different from /application ???? Or is the "/app" part a fixed value?

Comment: fixed value. i have to route to the same place for /app, /app/, or /app/whatever***. but /application is something else altogether.

Comment: that works, too, thanks! @cbuckley also provided a good solution above: ^/app(/.*)?$#

Answer (score 0):

```
^/(app1|app2)(?:/(.*))?$
```

matches all the below

`/app1` or `/app1/` or `/app1/whatever`
`/app2` or `/app2/` or `/app2/whatever`

```
^/app(?:/(.*))?$
```

will match
`/app` or `/app/` or `/app/whatever`

Answer (score 0):

(This is just building on what @jpschroeder already provided:) I liked the Regex matching I had but I wanted it to match on and include an *optional* ending slash.  When I placed

```
(\/*)
```

at the end of the Regex (just before the /g that was at the end of my Regex), things worked the way I wanted them to work.